# Hover function in PHP?

Tags: php, hover

Is there a way to use code something among the lines of:

```
if mouse.hover = True
```

in php?

Comment: php runs on the server and has no gui, period. there is no "hover" in php. you can use clientside javascript to do an ajax request on hover, but then that's not php...

Comment: Users can't hover over an element before the page has even been sent to the browser.

Comment: It's not even jQuery.  It's CSS.

Comment: `"but that's no use to me"` - Can you explain why?  And what you're trying to accomplish?  Because the simple answer to your question is "No, you can't do that in PHP."  You can, however, do that with JavaScript and/or CSS.  Why exactly doesn't that work in your situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't, because "hover" is a client-side event.

PHP as a server language can't check client actions.

The only way is using CSS for style event (changing color) or JS (like jQuery) for dynamic event.

Answer (score 1):

The hover method specifies two functions to run when the mouse pointer hovers over the selected elements.
This method triggers both the mouseenter and mouseleave events.
Now PHP as a server language and you know in server-side languages there is no way to find mouse movement. That's why it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

If What you're trying to do is to record if a client has hovered over a certain element, You can setup an endpoint in php which accepts, for example an Application/json as the request body , and then add onmouse(over/enter) Event Listeners using Javascript to the Elements that you need, collect the info you need inside the their callback functions, and then send them to the server for the desired outcome.
Preferably the data collected should be stored in a scope created for the specified procedure
(that doesn't guarantee security anyone can access the data being sent in the debugger
-hope this helps